# Convert array within array to averages

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

I am trying to convert:

```
var ic = [[[123,231,12],[56,43,124]],[[78,152,76],[64,132,200]]]
```

to (each element of the sub array has the average value of the sub array)

```
var ig = [[[122,122,122],[74,74,74]],[[102,102,102],[132,132,132]]]
```

Here is my code, the average function works, but it is not returning the correct new array:

```
var color2grey = function (image /* this is the image in color*/) {

const average = function([a,b,c]) {
return [((a+b+c)/3), ((a+b+c)/3), ((a+b+c)/3)]
};

return image.map(function(subArray) {
 average(subArray);
});

}
```

This is what I am getting:

```
returns- (2) [undefined, undefined] 0 : undefined 1 : undefined length : 2 proto : Array(0)
```

Comment: You could try adding the output you are getting, what the function returns so it helps in debugging.

Comment: returns-     (2) [undefined, undefined]
0
:
undefined
1
:
undefined
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` method to make new array and inside you can use `reduce()` to calculate average of each array and `Array.fill()` to add avg values to new array.

```js
var ic = [[[123,231,12],[56,43,124]],[[78,152,76],[64,132,200]]] 

var result = ic.map(a => a.map(function(e) {
  var avg = e.reduce((r, e) => r + e) / e.length
  return Array(e.length).fill(parseInt(avg))
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the outer arrays, get the average of the most inner array and map for each item the average value.

```js
var ic = [[[123, 231, 12], [56, 43, 124]], [[78, 152, 76], [64, 132, 200]]],
    ig = ic.map(function (a) {
        return a.map(function (b) {
            var avg = Math.floor(b.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }) / b.length);
            return b.map(function () { return avg; });
        });
    });

console.log(ig);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var avg = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length,
    ic = [[[123, 231, 12], [56, 43, 124]], [[78, 152, 76], [64, 132, 200]]],
    ig = ic.map(a => a.map(b => Array(b.length).fill(Math.floor(avg(b)))));

console.log(ig);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```